# How do I access direct descendants of a jquery object cleanly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, descendant

I have the following line in my js

```
var description = jqref.children('.category_info').children('.description').children('p').html();
```

which works exactly how I want it, though to me it feels way too clunky which feels like I am overlooking a better selector method.

I'm fairly certain I ought to be using the `>` direct child symbol but can't seem to implement it in the normal way as I am already dealing with a jquery object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) with the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).  I learned something new; you can prepend the selector with a child selector to make sure that you only get children:

```
var description = jqref.find('> .category_info > .description > p').html();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5SktL/

Comment: The problem with that is that there (may be) many descendants of jqref that match that selector. I only want the exact `jqref > .category_info > .description > p` item. This selector would also match `jqref > .children > otherref > .category_info > .description > p`

Comment: " I learned something new; you can prepend the selector with a child selector to make sure that you only get children" -- new to me too!

Comment: Nice! I did not know that you could start with a `>`